# How to write integral in latex

Tags: fonts, integral

[image]

I'd like to write a formula like this in the above picture.
But I got like this:

[image]

My code is: `\int_{\Omega} f(\bold{x})\, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} =`

1. Why the integral symbol looks rounded?
2. How to get the bolded "`x`" just like in the first picture?

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The upper picture uses the standard Computer Modern font, the lower picture some kind of Times font. You have something in your code which loads a Times font.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give an MWE, read [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: The problem is most likely your choice of fonts. Somewhere near the top of your tex file, you have something like \usepackage{...} with some font package name in the ...,

Answer (score 3):

The following code is a full example in which the integral takes the shape you want and the x is bold-font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} f\left( \bm{x} \right) d\bm{x} =
$
\end{document}
```

I think your problem is that you have not included the integral inside the dollar symbols (which represent the mathematical mode). For the bold font I use the package `bm`, which provides the function `\bm{...}` for including bold-font text in mathematical mode.

Maybe other possibility is the compiler you are using. In my case, compiling it with `pdfLaTeX`, I have had no problem.

Answer (score 2):

My welcome....in the community TeX.SE. For your question (I hope this time :-)) the answer is....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\int_{\Omega} f(\mathbf{x})\, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Previous answer:**
I think that your initial combination between Times New Roman (`newtxtext` - it is your clone) plus `txfonts`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\int_{\Omega} f(\mathbf{x})\, \mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the question is quite the opposite, isn't it? This is what she already has but she wants CM.

Comment: @campa You can see that I'm a scarce user with the English language :-(

Comment: Relax, I had to read the question a couple of times myself to be sure `:-)`

Comment: @campa Thank you very much for your comprension .